# Boolean length restriction in xsd file on soap service

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd

Is it possible to restrict length of boolean field, incoming on the service with 1 symbol in xsd file? So, will the following code be correct:

```
 <simpleType name="bool">
    <restriction base="boolean">
       <maxLength value="1"/>
    </restriction>
 </simpleType>
```

This is needed to prevent incoming "true" and "false" in specified field, because of this values will not processed correctly for some reasons and I can't change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the length facet is not applicable to the XSD boolean type.  (Since length applies to the value, not the lexical representation of the value, it would not in any case work the way you are thinking about.)

To require that 'true' and 'false' be avoided and the lexical forms '1' and '0' be used instead, use the pattern facet:

```
<simpleType name="bool">
  <restriction base="boolean">
    <pattern value="0|1"/>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```